# Fundamental group of the union of the unit circle, $X$-axis, and $Y$-axis

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have been solving some past exam questions and I came across the following question.

> Let  $X:= S_1 \cup (\mathbb R \times \{0\})\cup (\{0\}\times \mathbb R)$ be the union of the unit circle, the $X$-axis and the $Y$-axis. Compute the fundamental group of $X$ in terms of generators and relations.

I am not really sure how to go about this. My guess is that if I could find a retract of this space whose fundamental group is known then the question is solved. I am also wondering if the Seifert-van Kampen theorem would work but I have no clue. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You can find a homotopy equivalent space by contracting contractible parts of the space to points. First of all contract each component of the axes outside the unit disk to the point where it meets the unit disk. Now you have a graph and you can do the standard for graphs, namely contract all edges whose endpoints are distinct to points. The resulting graph is a wedge of circles.

Answer (score 2):

Your space is $X=S^1\cup(\mathbb R\times \{0\})\cup(\{0\}\times\mathbb R)$, which is the union of the circle of radius $1$ centered in $(0,0)$ with the $x$ and $y$ axis.
The space $X$ is homotopic to $S^1\cup (\{0\}\times I)\cup(I\times \{0\})$, so a circle with two diameters.
Our space has now the form $\oplus$ and if we identify the two diameters with a point we obtain the wedge sum of four circles, whose fundamental group is the free product on four generators with no relations: $\langle a,b,c,d|\emptyset \rangle$.
Therefore $\pi_1(X)\cong\pi^1(S^1\vee S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1)\cong\mathbb Z*\mathbb Z*\mathbb Z*\mathbb Z$.